# Get Notification from Android OS at a specific time even if application is killed

Tags: android, notifications, operating-system, android-notifications

I want to get a notification at a specific time, say at 8am and 8pm even if my application is not running.

Application must receive notification even if OS kill my application from background due to low memory.

I don't want to use Push Notification as it will require a dedicated server which I don't have.

Is there any functionality like iOS has, where OS send notification or Silent message to application irrespective if application is in memory or it is closed/Forced stop by OS/user.

Comment: use `BroadcastReceiver` with `AlarmManager`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AlarmManager. It has these characteristics:

... operate outside of your application, so you can use them to trigger events or actions even when your app is not running, and even if the device itself is asleep. [Link to documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Comment: When an application force closes all the services, alarm manager, broadcast receivers are stopped. What can we do in this case.

Comment: Just register your receiver in manifest (not in code) to detach it from your application lifecycle

Comment: will this work if my application is force stopped by the user? Can I have a link to sample code

Comment: why not ) [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestReceiver) is a proof link for receiver's behaviour: "The receiver tag declares an BroadcastReceiver class that is available as part of the package's application components, allowing the application to receive actions or data broadcast by other applications even if it is not currently running." And [here](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/Scheduler.zip) you can find a sample.